# How to troubleshoot periodic I/O issues with an SD card reader

Tags: windows-7, sd-card

I have a 128GB SD card with all my music on it plugged into a Windows 7 laptop.  I have winamp installed on the laptop and the library points to the music on the SD card.  Every now and then winamp will freeze due to what I believe is some sort of issue reading from the drive.  It'll sometimes become responsive again on it's own, but it will usually become unresponsive again pretty quickly.  If I try to access the card through Explorer during this time, Explorer will also hang.  Physically ejecting the card (which I really don't like doing) and plugging it back in will bring everything back into working order...until the next time it happens, which could be a few hours or even days later.

Are there any Windows logs or other troubleshooting steps I can take when this happens to find out what is going on?

A few other notes/observations:

1. I haven't gotten a chance to try a different SD card, so I'm not sure if it's the card itself or the reader.  I also haven't tried the same card in a different computer.
2. I don't believe it is a corrupt file that is causing it since re-inserting the card and playing the same song again works.
3. The music directory on the SD card was being shared on the network with the read permissions set to a select few users.  Perhaps there are computers out there trying to scan through network resources and that is causing heavy access to the drive.  I just turned off the sharing and will see if that fixes it.  If that was the issue, is there something I can look at to see what was pegging it?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  The crux of the question is whether there are any logs that would help me to determine what the nature of the problem is.

Comment: I have deleted my comment as your response basically indicates to me your not willing to rule out those possibilities.  When you decide to rule out those possible causes, edit your question, once you do that I will provide an answer.

Comment: It's not that I am unwilling to rule those out as possibilities.  Even if it is a defective card, I would be interested in knowing whether there are logs that would help indicate such an issue.